# Questionable borders on seazone 3

Tags: axis-and-allies

When my friends and I play Axis & Allies 1942 we have trouble distinguishing a couple borders along seazone 3, pictured below. In each case you can see a little sliver of land that is barely touching seazone 3, one in the UK and the other in Karelia. However, the other seazone-territory borders are pretty clearly indicated, so do we assume UK and Karelia are not intended to border seazone 3 because they are not as clear as others? [image: UK][image: Karelia]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the official [FAQ here](http://harrisgamedesign.com/pdf/A&A_1942_FAQ.pdf)

> **Q: Does Sea Zone 3 connect to the United Kingdom?**
>   A: Yes,

If my memory serves correctly, that is [Scapa Flow](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Scapa+Flow,+United+Kingdom/@57.9514883,-4.9893283,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x489afd5bbba7aa4f:0x283fcf6f1a7a8ecc).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Based on the ruling about sea zone 17 and Algeria in that FAQ, which is a similar situation to sea zone 3 and Karelia, I'm going to go with no intended connection on that side.

Comment: Good answer. Don’t you think that’s kind of ridiculous?  I love the game, but there are many flaws with the 1942 SE map. The worst of which is how small some of the territories are.

Answer (score 1):

I know that sea zone 14 does not connect to balkans (Saw that on the official site) and what you show here is kind of the same thing so i wouldnt consider them as connecting. So i would say no it dosnt connect

Comment: Could you cite where you saw that?